# SQL query to find distinct elements not working

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I wanted to run a query where I will get all the fields where one field is unique.I tried this

```
Select * from announcements where title = SELECT distinct title 
FROM announcements;
```

But it's not working. Can anyone please help me out here.

Comment: Is it possible you have the same title with different case?

Answer (score 1):

```
Select * 
  from announcements 
 where title in (SELECT distinct title 
FROM announcements)
```

Comment: This will return all the rows of the table (except the null titles if they exist).

Answer (score 1):

This query:

```
select title 
from announcements 
group by title 
having count(*) = 1
```

returns all the unique titles.
Use it with the operator `IN`:

```
select * from announcements 
where title in (
  select title 
  from announcements 
  group by title 
  having count(*) = 1
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try use round brackets

Like:
Select * from announcements where title in (SELECT distinct title
FROM announcements);

Comment: This will return all the rows of the table (except the null titles if they exist).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all. I got what I was looking for

```
SELECT MIN( id ) AS id, title, issue_date, expirty_date, is_active FROM announcements GROUP BY title ORDER BY issue_date DESC
```

Comment: This query has nothing to do with your question.